# Hide certain span Elements with first and last-child

Tags: html, css

I've following HTML structure

```
<div class="conditinal-area">
  <div class="conditions">
    <span class="condition-labels">
        <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
        <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
        <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
<div class="conditinal-area">
  <div class="conditions">
    <span class="condition-labels">
        <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
        <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
        <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
<div class="conditinal-area">
  <div class="conditions">
    <span class="condition-labels">
        <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
        <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
        <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Now I like to hide all *IF*, *ELSEIF*, *ELSE* with CSS and show:

- *IF* on the **first**  `.conditional-area`
- *ELSE* on the **last**  `.conditional-area`
- *ELSEIF* on the **other**  `.conditional-area`

This [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/24L3gw8u/) with following CSS:

```
.condition-labels span{
    display:none;
}
.conditinal-area:first-child .condition-labels span:first-child{
    display:inline;
}
.conditinal-area .condition-labels span.condition-elseif{
    display:inline;
}
.conditinal-area:first-child .condition-labels span.condition-elseif{
    display:none;
}
.conditinal-area:last-child .condition-labels span:last-child{
    display:inline;
}
.conditinal-area:last-child .condition-labels span.condition-elseif{
    display:none;
}
```

**BUT**

Adding content before or after the HTML causes that *IF* and *ELSE* to be hidden: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24L3gw8u/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but adding random content before and after the elements will mess up the children references, and there's no way around it. There's no such thing as `n-of-class`.

If you need to place content before/after those elements, I suggest you wrap them in a div, so you will keep the children references intact.

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/24L3gw8u/4/)

```
<div>content before</div>
<div> <!-- WRAPPER DIV -->
    <div class="conditinal-area">
        <div class="conditions">
            <span class="condition-labels">
                <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
                <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
                <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        1
    </div>
    <div class="conditinal-area">
        <div class="conditions">
            <span class="condition-labels">
                <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
                <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
                <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        2
    </div>
    <div class="conditinal-area">
        <div class="conditions">
            <span class="condition-labels">
                <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
                <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
                <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        3
    </div>
    <div class="conditinal-area">
        <div class="conditions">
            <span class="condition-labels">
                <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
                <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
                <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        4
    </div>
</div>
<div>content after</div>
```

Comment: That's how I did it!

Answer (score 1):

I changed "content before" and "content after" to `<p>` tag, so we can then use `nth-of-type()` selector properly. You could also wrap all the conditional divs into a container too.

http://jsfiddle.net/g2Ljqf6j/

```css
.conditinal-area:not(:first-of-type) .condition-if,
.conditinal-area:not(:last-of-type) .condition-else,
.conditinal-area:first-of-type .condition-elseif,
.conditinal-area:last-of-type .condition-elseif {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>content before</p>

<div class="conditinal-area">
  <div class="conditions">
    <span class="condition-labels">
        <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
        <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
        <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
    </span>
  </div>
    1
</div>
<div class="conditinal-area">
  <div class="conditions">
    <span class="condition-labels">
        <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
        <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
        <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
    </span>
  </div>
    2
</div>
<div class="conditinal-area">
  <div class="conditions">
    <span class="condition-labels">
        <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
        <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
        <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
    </span>
  </div>
    3
</div>
<div class="conditinal-area">
  <div class="conditions">
    <span class="condition-labels">
        <span class="condition-if">IF</span>
        <span class="condition-elseif">ELSEIF</span>
        <span class="condition-else">ELSE</span>
    </span>
  </div>
    4
</div>

<p>content after</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first-of-type` and `last-of-type`.

```
.condition-labels span{
  display:none;
}
.conditinal-area:first-of-type .condition-labels span:first-of-type{
  display:inline;
}
.conditinal-area .condition-labels span.condition-elseif{
  display:inline;
}
.conditinal-area:first-of-type .condition-labels span.condition-elseif{
  display:none;
}
.conditinal-area:last-of-type .condition-labels span:last-of-type{
  display:inline;
}
.conditinal-area:last-of-type .condition-labels span.condition-elseif{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: same result: http://jsfiddle.net/24L3gw8u/2/

Comment: `nth-of-type` selects by type, not by class. Since all elements are `div`s, it's not useful.